# Force Nginx to send Content-Length header for static files with gzip?

Tags: nginx, http-headers, gzip, static-content

We're running Nginx 0.7.65[-1ubuntu2.3]. I've just noticed that when serving local static files using an `alias` directive and `gzip on`, the `Content-Length` header is not getting sent. Since it's serving files from the local filesystem, it shouldn't have any problem getting the length. How can I force Nginx to send a `Content-Length` header with these files?

Comment: Related: https://serverfault.com/questions/482875/nginx-removes-content-length-header-for-chunked-content

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It turns out that when using [dynamic Gzip](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_gzip_module.html#gzip_http_version) then the `Content-Length` header is not sent, as the `Transfer-Encoding` is `chunked`. Pre-compressing my files and switching to [static Gzip](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_gzip_static_module.html#gzip_static) allows Nginx to know ahead of time the file size and send an appropriate `Content-Length` header.

Comment: I recommend using `x-file-size` below

Answer (score 1):

Here's a performant Nginx solution to add a `x-file-size` header:

https://github.com/AnthumChris/fetch-progress-indicators/issues/13

```
## Nginx Lua module must be installed https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/dynamic-modules/lua/
## https://github.com/openresty/lua-nginx-module#header_filter_by_lua
header_filter_by_lua_block {
  function file_len(file_name)
    local file = io.open(file_name, "r")

    if (file == nil) then return -1 end

    local size = file:seek("end")
    file:close()
    return size
  end

  ngx.header["X-File-Size"] = file_len(ngx.var.request_filename);
}
```