# Which static file types does Nginx generate ETags for by default?

Tags: nginx, http-headers, gzip, etags

In modern versions of Nginx, the ETag is [automatically generated](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35806397/1718491) for static file types, even if you don't specifically enable the `etag on` in your location blocks or otherwise:

https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#etag

For example, your PNG or JPEG files served by Nginx will automatically include the HTTP headers for `content-length`, `last-modified`, and `etag` on static files that are not gzipped even if you don't manually enable them...

However, what file types does Nginx do this for by default? When I tested this by including `.html` file extensions in my static files location block, and manually added `etag on` to all of my "static" file types (including `.html` files, even though they are not typically considered static), <s>Nginx stripped out the `etag` HTTP header for my `.html` files (even though it was hardcode enabled in the location block) but not other file types such as PNG or JPEG.</s>

*Update: it was Cloudflare stripping out the `etag` header on my .html files and not Nginx. However, Nginx does strip the `content-length` header when gzip is enabled on certain file types. To make matters more confusing, Cloudflare adds gzip on some content automatically.*

I don't see any documentation about this... which files types will Nginx automatically enable ETags for, and which file types will Nginx ignore/strip ETags for by default?

Edit: These gzip related discussion might be related:

https://javorszky.co.uk/2019/03/28/etag-if-match-nginx-and-you/

https://forum.nginx.org/read.php?2,286645,286645#msg-286645

https://forum.nginx.org/read.php?2,240120,240120#msg-240120

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55305687/how-to-address-weak-etags-conversion-by-nginx-on-gzip-compression

> TIL that Nginx strips weak ETags from upstream responses when
> gzipping them for "Accept-Encoding: gzip". Thanks, internet.

https://twitter.com/tomstuart/status/367994690517225472

Comment: Please share your full configuration as shown by `nginx -T`.

Comment: Thanks @TeroKilkanen but this is meant to be a generic question, it's not really a case specific error but seeking documentation.

Comment: Are you sure that your configuration doesn't affect the behavior in any way?

Comment: Okay I will run some tests with gzip disabled and report back, but that is a secondary to what I'm hoping someone knows re: file types and ETag behavior... to confirm, this server does have gzip enabled in the `nginx.conf`.

Comment: I'm reporting back that disabling gzip in Nginx, and then disabling Cloudflare (which adds gzip to text/html content) did indeed recover my missing ETag headers for `.html` files I was testing on my server. In fact, even when I didn't set `etag on;` Nginx still decided to send an ETag header for my HTML files, so this does seem to be gzip related.

Comment: Final update: the `etag` header was being stripped by Cloudflare, not Nginx.

Answer (score 0):

What I've discovered is that Nginx will strip the `content-length` header from certain file types such as my `.html` files if your server has gzip enabled. However, the `etag` header does seem to remain intact unless you are using Cloudflare, which strips `etag` headers from certain content.

To make matters more confusing, Cloudflare adds gzip to certain content even if Nginx has gzip disabled... for example, HTML or dynamic content, etc.

Now I'm still confused here, because [my understanding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55860358/why-the-nginx-etag-value-generated-by-last-modified-time-and-content-length) is that Nginx generates ETags based on the `content-length` and `last-modified` headers, so I don't know how the `etag` header can remain on e.g. .html or .js or .css files that are being gzipped already by Nginx, because `content-length` is already stripped by Nginx in such cases due to gzip being enabled...

According to [one dude](https://serverfault.com/questions/529621/forcing-nginx-to-send-content-length-headers-when-serving-static-files-with-gzip), using static gzip instead can solve the `content-length` dilemna, but that's another challenge for those not interested in using static gzip.

But back to the primary question, what file types does Nginx generate Etags for by default?... well, I'm still not sure the answer to this question but I'm guessing maybe Nginx will generate ETags for any file on disk that has a `last-modified` timestamp and a static `content-length` value... even if Nginx strips out `content-length` because of gzip. Yah, I don't get it either.